# Jquery-Steps plug in not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I came across this amazing plugin http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples
I am have been trying to make it work but it seems I am missing something.

**I have added the reference to the file :**

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.steps.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**My markup looks like this :**

```
<div id="example-basic">
    <h3>Keyboard</h3>
    <section>
        <p>Try the keyboard navigation by clicking arrow left or right!</p>
    </section>
    <h3>Effects</h3>
    <section>
        <p>Wonderful transition effects.</p>
    </section>
    <h3>Pager</h3>
    <section>
        <p>The next and previous buttons help you to navigate through your content.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

**Javascript looks like this :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#example-basic").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true
});
</script>
```

Comment: Any console errors? Have you included jQuery reference? Try wrapping your code inn DOM ready handler `$(function(){})`

Comment: @ShaunakD TypeError: $(...).steps is not a function

Comment: It seems the plugin is not loading. Verify the path `../Scripts/jquery.steps.min.js`. Also, where are you including the reference in HTML?

Comment: @ShaunakD yes i have added jquery-1.11.2.js reference and tried placing the javascript inside dom ready

Comment: @ShaunakD I have dragged and dropped the file from the solution explorer on to my page. So there is a very little chance or error.

Comment: Where in your HTML sections are you including `<script src="../Scripts/jquery.steps.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` ?

Comment: @ShaunakD below `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">` 

I am using a master page.

Comment: It looks like `jquery.steps.min` is included after `$("#example-basic").steps` is executed

Comment: @Arbaaz have you added the jquery library file ?

Comment: The should be above the `<asp:Content..`

Comment: @MairajAhmad  i have added jquery-1.11.2.js reference 

I am not getting `TypeError: $(...).steps is not a function ` anymore. But its still not working

Comment: @ShaunakD no it cant be above. The code wont `Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.`

Comment: Place the jquery code at end of page.

Comment: Ok i think its kinda working now but it looks horrible. Am I missing CSS ? Is there a css file for this plug in?

Answer (score 3):

You need to link this CSS file, [download it here](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/blob/master/demo/css/jquery.steps.css)

and add the following line in you `head` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/jquery.steps.css"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

We have to use latest jquery as this plugin uses when function of the jquery. This solved my problem.
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js

Comment: didnt solve my problem. It seems to be working but it looks horrible as if css is missing.

Comment: add the link to this css -> http://www.jquery-steps.com/Content/Examples?v=zY_RpLQAM_2YuBnTHKA2t9GIGyqXY4KhLU1OJRLrY8M1 in you file

Comment: that worked.  It it seems to be messing with my existing css on the page. But thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must place the last script code right before the close of the body tag like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="steps">
        <h1>First Step</h1>
        <section>First Content</section>

        <h1>Second Step</h1>
        <section>Second Content</section>
    </div>
    <script>
    $("#steps").steps(
    {
      headerTag : "h1",
      bodyTag : "section",
      cssClass: "wizard"
    }
        );
  </script>
</body>
```

Also, this an essential css file that must be inplace:

```
<script src="./javascripts/jquery.steps.js"></script>
```

This can be found on the project's git hub page.